# Failed multi upload when images size goes height

Tags: php, upload, height, size

I'm using php to upload my pics but when my selected images size goes to height
my upload failed. On the page no error show for this happend  This is like refresh page but my selected images size is lower than 3 MG it Works Well 
whats my problems.

PLEASE HELP ME.

```
$output_dir = "../PostImage/";
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
    $ret = array();

    $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
   {

        if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
        {
            $RandomNum   = time();
            $ImagePostName=jdate("HisYmd",$timestamp)."".$RandomNum."".convert_filename_to_md5($_POST['title'])."".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $ImagePostName);


        }
        else
        {
            $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
            for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
            {
                $RandomNum   = time();
                $ImagePostName=jdate("HisYmd",$timestamp)."".$RandomNum."".convert_filename_to_md5($_POST['title'])."".$_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$ImagePostName );

            }
        }
    }
}





<form name="form1"  method="post"  action="index.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="form-control input-lg m-bot15" name="myfile[]" id="myfile"  multiple="multiple"  type="file"/>
<input  type="submit" value="upload" placeholder=""/> 
</form>
```

Comment: `$error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];` Well it would probably be a good idea **to check this error code rather than just move it to another variable**

Comment: Also you allow multiple file uploads **but you dont actually process multiple files in your code** It would probably be of some use **if you Read The Flippin Manual** [Its here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)

Comment: Also you have a braced section `{}` that is not illegal but serves no purpose

Comment: so this is from my apache server . a have to fix it from apache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M

After modifying php.ini file(s), you need to restart your HTTP server to use new configuration.

If you can't change your php.ini, you're out of luck. You cannot change these values at run-time; uploads of file larger than the value specified in php.ini will have failed by the time execution reaches your call to ini_set.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your php.ini, you're out of luck. You cannot change these values at run-time; uploads of file larger than the value specified in php.ini will have failed by the time execution reaches your call to ini_set.